# Enviar imagem da câmera para o servidor pelo Retrofit

Tags: android, web-service, retrofit

Aprendi a enviar uma imagem da pasta *drawable* para meu servidor na rede utilizando a *lib* Retrofit, mas não estou conseguindo enviar de um `ImageView`, que recebeu da captura da câmera. Crio uma classe que converte a imagem do *drawable* para *bytes*, que receberá da `MainActivity`, acessando a pasta *drawable*. Como fazer isso, acessando um `ImageView`. Sei acessar o `bitmap` do `Imageview`, mas não sei como enviar o `bitmap` para a classe de conversão para *byte*; na verdade, não também como fazer a classe de conversão receber esse `bitmap`. Vou deixar os códigos da classe de conversão e da `MainActivity`. A questão é: como tratar esse código para enviar um `bitmap` acessado em um `ImageView`: `Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`

```
//Clsse para conversão do bitmap para byte
 public class BinaryBytes {

    public static byte[] getResourceInBytes( Context context, int resource )   {
    final Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resource);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    return( byteArray );
}

public static String getResourceName( Context context, int resource ){
    return( context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(resource) );
}

}



// Código do acesso à pasta drawable e do envio para o servidor

        String imageName = BinaryBytes.getResourceName(this, R.drawable.jeep); //BinaryBytes
        byte[] imageBinary = BinaryBytes.getResourceInBytes(this, R.drawable.jeep);

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), imageBinary);

        call = carAPI.sendImg("send-img", imageName, requestBody);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Car>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Car> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Error SEND IMG: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209319/sending-an-image-file-post-with-retrofit

Comment: Caique, o link não trata do meu problema.

Comment: Tente pelo _path_ da foto para enviar pelo Retrofit como um `TypedFile`

Comment: A foto fica temporariamente em um ImageView; porque foi capturada pela câmera do smartphone. Consigo acessar o bitmap do ImageView, mas não estou conseguindo enviar para a classe BinaryBytes porque esta espera uma imagem e um nome da imagem que está no projeto. Como minha imagem não está no projeto e sim em um ImageView, não consigo fazer as mudanças devidas.

Answer (score 7):

Com Retrofit você pode utilizar `Multipart Upload` para enviar uma imagem. Mas é necessário que você salve a foto no seu dispositivo, nem que seja só para fazer o upload e depois deleta-la. [Na documentação](https://gist.github.com/inktomi/5391583) ensina como enviar um objeto Bitmap da seguinte forma:

  1 - Gera um objeto Bitmap a partir da foto

  2 - Salva este Bitmap em um arquivo JPG

  3 - Cria um TypedFile a partir do arquivo JPG:

```
TypedFile image = new TypedFile("image/jpeg", imageFileName);
```

  4 - Cria uma interface para utilizar com o Retrofit e adiciona a Annotation @Multipart no método de upload. Repare que o TypedFile é o tipo de arquivo que será enviado, o Retrofit se encarrega de coverte-lo para bytes[] e executar a requisição POST:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("/user/me/avatar?access_token={access_token}")
    void uploadAvatar(@Name("access_token") String accessToken, @Name("avatar") TypedFile image, retrofit.http.Callback<Boolean> callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar imagem para o servidor eu usei assim na nova versão:

```
@Multipart
@POST("xpto/upload")
public Call<AnuncioRest> upload(@Part("file\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"") RequestBody file,
                                @Part("descricao") RequestBody descricao);
```

E chamo da seguinte forma:

```
 public AnuncioRest createAnuncio(final Anuncio anuncio, final AnuncioActivity anuncioActivity){
    try {
        showProgress(anuncioActivity,"Aguarde","Criando seu anúncio...");
        AnuncioService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(AnuncioService.class);

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), anuncio.getFotoProduto());
        RequestBody descricao= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), anuncio.getDescricao());
        Call<AnuncioRest> call = service.upload(requestBody, descricao);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<AnuncioRest>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AnuncioRest> call, Response<AnuncioRest> response) {

            }
        }...
```